# How to interpert a qq plot

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

I'm a little confused about how to interpert this qq plot. The huge gap between the values makes me think it's not the best normal distribution, but i'm not sure how to draw a good conclusion out of the following data. Help is highly appreciated !!

[image: QQ PLOT]

Comment: Closed, So I can't give a formal answer. However, with only $n = 26$ observations there are almost sure to be some 'gaps' in a normal probability plot. The important thing is that the points on your plot don't stray very far from the diagonal reference line. // You can look at the plots in the suggested link.

Comment: If you try the R code `qqnorm(rnorm(28,0,16))` several times, you get similar charts which do come from sampling a normal distribution (though the chart is transposed).  In your chart, the vertical steps (horizontal in R) are determined by the procedure so are automatically what you should expect, while the horizontal steps (vertical in R) do not look particularly bad

Comment: @BruceET Hi Bruce, thankyou for your answer! but by looking at my line i can see that only about 7-8 points are on the line and that most points are kind of not on a straight line. could i use that to argument that the data is only standardly distrubited to some small extent? thankyou in advance.

Comment: thankyou ! @Henry